# Add rep to navigation community list

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app

When looking at the navigation menu in the iOS app, it would be nice to see your rep total on the right side as it's shown in the topbar's Site Selector:

[image: Menu Tray]

Comment: There doesn't seem to be much room there (even less on my android). Are you suggesting a wider menu, smaller font, truncated site names, etc?

Comment: @Geobits I'd leave that to SE's stellar Mobile team to figure out. It most likely would mean any or all of the items you listed. This current menu was designed for the content shown. Adding in new content changes the design and the design requirements. I'm not suggesting *how* it should be done, just that I'd like to *see* it done in some way.

Comment: a fourth option could be a second row of data, with rep/badges under the site name. otherwise while i like the suggestion i agree there just isn't enough room

Comment: @mhlester If the current designed was completely maintained -- yes there isn't enough room. But adding a feature means you're making room for it not just shoehorning it in. Keeping it on the same line would maintain how SE handles display community name + rep in the Site Switcher and Profile pages too. When I see a list of Community names, I kind of expect to see my rep on the right too.

Comment: don't get me wrong, i support this feature request (**+1**)! i'm just fleshing out the options

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The next build will feature your reputation on the side.  I tried subtitles but given how short the reputation is, this felt more natural.

So far all I've done is increased the menu width by 10pt while typically consuming 23pt, so some names that wasn't ellipsized before probably now are.

[image: Reputation on the side]

Comment: Out of curiosity, if I wanted to ask the same thing for the Android app, should I open another question? It seems silly to do so, but I don't know who in the mobile team sees/does/answers what.

Comment: @Geobits I'd say open a new question so they Android guys can track it.  If it's not on a list somewhere so we can assign it, we just fix things by chance.

Comment: Very nice! Any thought of badge circles too, or just too cramped?

Comment: Badges would help fill out a second line but it could get noisy at that point.  Not sure.

Comment: Very cool @BrianNickel! Can't wait!

Comment: Why not [meta-tag:status-completed] then? :)

Comment: Because I'm forgetful.