# Add rep to navigation menu

Tags: feature-request, android-app

After seeing the [mockup for this feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222097/212780) in the iOS app, I'm feeling slightly jealous.

Can we please get something like this included for the Android version? I'm unsure of the best way to do it. The menu on my Nexus 5 is almost as wide as the screen is now. Sites with long names (EL&U Meta in particular) already wrap to the next line, so maybe making them wrap slightly shorter would work?

[image]

(Just pretend this screenshot isn't iOS or blue. I can't grab a screen now.)

Comment: Apple is more beautiful, sorry to break it to ya

Comment: @Adel If you like orange icons on blue, sure it is. They look better on gray, though :)