# Increase reputation required to add "k" in SE app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, reputation, android-app, ios-app

> [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) - Reputation is no longer shortened in iOS and Android apps as in my example image
>   [image]

---

Because it is not informative, especially for the users, having not a lot reputation (me on SO - 1,185 rep). My reputation behind my answer or question showed as "1k". SE sites starting to add "k" after 9,999 rep, and app - after 999 rep. It would be better if app has the same >9,999 rep to show "k" instead of thousands.

[image]

Comment: Might want to specify which app you're referring to, or maybe add both apps' tags if you happen to know this behavior is common to both.

Comment: Official StackExchange app.

Comment: Right, but there's one for Android, and another for iOS. (I'd bet that both to behave the same.)

Comment: @NickStauner android.

Comment: just looked at some screen shots, it currently looks the same on ios and android, so the request should probably apply to both.

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl thanks for retag.

Comment: *generally* it's been requested that ios and android be tagged separately, in case one gets completed before the other

Comment: Yikes! There goes....93% of your rep!

Comment: Only 69 more upvotes and I'll get back my rep ))))

Comment: According to [Benford's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford's_law), the most common leading digit — about one third of the time — should be 1. Therefore, a good UX guideline would be to start abbreviating not at 1k or 10k, but at 2k or 20k.

Comment: Riiight, if the purpose of the k were something more than abbreviation. That's all it is though. Although I'll admit one thing I was looking forward to about hitting 10k was the abbreviated display

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Update:
This is also now implemented on Android as of version 1.0.35, we no longer trim any reputation count less than 10k and we don't trim reputation at all on the "Users" page.

---

This is finished for iOS. The app is using the website's behavior:

1. We are no longer shortening badge count anywhere.  As was said `strlen("9900") == strlen("9.9k")` and kerning (don't forget kerning) would only really save you a few pixels.
2. We only shorten reputation when we're space constrained.  That is, in the menu and below posts.  Below posts is really space constrained and even shortened posts will look bad.
3. Reputation below 10,000 is rendered in long form with a comma.  Users in this camp don't have 1000 badges.

Here's screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image: Jon Skeet happy]

Still a problem I'm ruminating on:

[image: Jon Skeet sad]

Comment: Now that the app is out your goal should be to have enough rep on Meta that you can recreate the edge conditions here yourself.

Comment: Khm. Which reps?

Comment: @nicael Probably about what mhlester described. Looking forward to that 0.35k bounty.

Comment: Suspect you are planning for iOS app first. But I am on Android, so, please, don't forget about android app.

Comment: @nicael don't worry, Android is going to get it too.

Comment: Maybe instead of all those badges you can just say **lots** ;)

Comment: When will be Android app updated?

Comment: @nicael I believe it is already on it's way to the play store.

Comment: Perfect. Except... Why is it space instead of comma as a delimiter?

Comment: Could you just drop the time from posts that are > 1 year old if space is an issue?  E.g. leave it as "Edited Jan 16 '12".

Comment: What happens when Skeet earns another 4400 bronze badges?

Comment: I think you mean "keming".

Answer (score 9):

There are a number of different places where reputation is displayed. I understand the need to be more concise in the app with its smaller screen, but currently it's shortened *everywhere*. It should be taken on a case by case basis. My thoughts:

---

### <del>No</del> Yes

**Post "signature"** - <del>I think this one should stay truncated. Depending on the number of badges and the timestamp, a larger display *may* be dangerous</del>

I've given this one more thought. The only situation where it doesn't fit, is when there are literally [thousands of badges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HqEI.jpg). *Nobody* has that many badges between 1k and 10k, so I can't think why it should be different from the website

> [image]

### No

**Sidebar** ([exclusive to iOS app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222063/add-rep-to-navigation-community-list)) - Absolutely not. It's so cramped already. There are some pretty long site names. Also, the value there is cached, so could be far out of date.

> [image]

---

### Yes

**Profile page** - This is where I'd like to see not just a longer amount (10k vs 1k), but rather show the *full* reputation (10432). As it is, there's *no* way to see true reputation, and I think that's valuable. Especially for self-navel-gazing. I think it's important to be able to see that information *somewhere*

> [image]

---

Anywhere else I'm missing?

Comment: where do we have reputation in a sidebar? I can't find it.

Comment: ah nvm, I only compared images of question/answer screen shots of the android and ios app earlier, which infact behave the same way with rep shortening. Profile page seems to behave different and android app doesn't show rep in the sidebar at all.

Comment: added screenshots, but yes, looks like android doesn't have that

Comment: Anyways, I agree with you on the profile page and find it weird that the ios version doesn't show the full rep whilst the [android version does](https://i.imgur.com/MSlBxp0.png). I don't agree on the post signature tho, if even [Jon Skeet got enough place for his rep/badges](https://i.imgur.com/WiZatUF.png) I think we should at least show up to 9,999 rep without truncation. Both screen shots taken in portrait mode on htc one so probably one of the bigger screens, but still.

Comment: Here be breakage: http://i.stack.imgur.com/7HqEI.jpg (don't know why image uploaded got blurry. Sorry bout that)

Comment: 100% agreement from me for changing it in these locations. The post signature one will be a bit tricky on Android (due to lots of different screen sizes) but should be fine on iOS, I think.

Comment: Consider though @Kasra, this request only changes the signature for 1000-9999 reputation users. Most badges being tag badges, nobody at that low level has enough to cause breakage

Comment: In fact, `9900` is no more characters than `672k`, so why make it `9.9k`?

Comment: In fact, `9900` is no more characters than `9.9k` )))

Comment: Oh! Counting! Hard