# Notices of protected questions on child metas

Tags: feature-request, per-site-meta, protected-questions, post-notices

[image]

I saw this notice on [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250068/february-2014-stack-overflow-community-moderator-election-results) question on Meta Stack Overflow. 

I think that "you must have earned at least 10 reputation **on this site**" is not really true, it should be "you must have earned at least 10 reputation **on the main site**", because you can't earn rep on metas.

Comment: the word "earned" is also not 100% accurate, as indicated eg in other MSE post: [Stack Exchange doesn't allow me to answer protected questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231498/stack-exchange-doesnt-allow-me-to-answer-protected-questions)

Comment: @gnat "other MSE post: " it is my post too )). But there is another problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

But the reputation can take up to an hour to update from the main site to the meta site. So your reputation may not always match what is on the main site. The change would be misleading as it would imply that once you achieve that reputation on the main site, you immediately have access to post an answer there, which is not true.

I think a better and more sensible solution would just be eliminating the word "earned" on per-site metas if it's *really* confusing people.

Comment: But the "earned" is there for another reason: it's not enough to simply _have_ >10 reputation on a site; people who have 101 reputation from the rep bonus still can't answer a protected question. You _must have earned 10 reputation on that site_ in order to answer it. (Though I don't know if anyone who didn't already know this would pick up this subtlety.)