# Why can't I use the Formatting Sandbox?

Tags: support, privileges, protected-questions

I tried to post an answer in the [Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

I got this:

[image: Banner that locks me out]

...but I am able to [post a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox#comment784032_3122) in the formatting sandbox

[image: A test comment screenshot]

...and I have more than 10 rep on MSE:

[image: my rep]

One needs 10 reputation to post an answer in a protected post, but I have more than 10, and I am allowed to post comments, which is a 50 rep privilege.

Then why am I not allowed to post an answer in the formatting sandbox?

Comment: I unprotected it, now you can post your answers. (it got auto protected, probably after deletion of several answers from low rep users)

Comment: Cheers, it's a never ending battle with Community account since answers there get deleted very often. If it happens again feel free to ping me here, or ask in the Tavern from any 15k user to unprotect it again. :-)

Comment: I checked how [bullets and headings](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/239217#239217) work in the formatting sandbox

Comment: Nice, fair use of the sandbox. :-)

Comment: Much time passed since... :)

Comment: It all started here @nic, I really wanted to earn 10 repz that day :)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231498/stack-exchange-doesnt-allow-me-to-answer-protected-questions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You only have 2 rep **earned** on this site.

The other 101 points come from the initial 1 everyone gets and the 100 point account association bonus.

So to be able to edit protected questions (which the sandbox question is) you need to have at least 111 reputation here.