# Can we get a special (unprotected) sandbox for the stack exchange API?

Tags: feature-request, api, protected-questions

Can we have a special Stack Exchange site for testing out the API? I know about the [formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) and the [API sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51812/the-api-sandbox) already, but they're protected so I can't answer the question as a new user (and the 100+ trusted user bonus doesn't count).

I read [this related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239213/why-cant-i-use-the-formatting-sandbox) and it seems the problem is that the post gets auto-protected when a certain number of answers are deleted.

I know this is potentially asking for a lot but I feel there's an artificial barrier of entry to use the API, because to test it one needs to have XP on the [meta.stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) site.

---

Edit: Thanks [Tim Stone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/150235/tim-stone) for sharing [this related post](https://stackapps.com/questions/4608/allow-registrant-to-use-write-access-without-linking-stack-apps-post) on testing the API's write functionality, and [ᔕᖺᘎᕊ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/260841/%E1%94%95%E1%96%BA%E1%98%8E%E1%95%8A) for [this other post](https://web.archive.org/web/20150908145957/https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21244/is-there-a-current-staff-dev-response-to-this-proposal) about a failed proposal to do exactly what I'm asking here.

Comment: There was an Area51 proposal for a 'Sandbox' site, but it didn't get far :(

Comment: nuu @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ any idea why? :O

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20150908145957/http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/21244/is-there-a-current-staff-dev-response-to-this-proposal basically because it would have been a lot of effort to implement but little to gain :/

Comment: Unfortunately not the [only roadblock](http://stackapps.com/questions/4608/allow-registrant-to-use-write-access-without-linking-stack-apps-post), but yeah, it's annoying. Hmm…

Comment: Awww, that's disappointing. I totally get where they're coming from, but still strange that that've released a nice v2 API with write functionality, that can only be tested with some difficulty. I understand not needing a sandbox for a read-only API, but it seems pretty crucial for when you wanna create/update an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Start a new question? Use this post for testing? Seems like the solution is straightforward here. :) The API Sandbox got protected due to too many answers being posted... I unprotected it for now, which will probably give it another answer or two.

On the upshot, your profile here now also has enough rep to answer protected questions anyway.

Comment: Hehe I was just about to comment about that :) Funny how it works, lol

Comment: However, if I had no other choice, I would still feel hesitant about posting a new question for the sake of testing the API... I feel like the community would downvote it to oblivion, haha. Any thoughts? I just want to make sure I don't become an obnoxious part of the community :D

Comment: @Titus Well, the other sandbox did well... Personally, I wouldn't be opposed to closing/deleting the old one and opening up a new one. That seems like a reasonable thing to do every few years as clutter from old API tests and even versions builds up.

Comment: thanks for the input @Adam :) Haha if anything, I think the Formatting Sandbox (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) needs to be closed. It keeps crashing Chrome when I try to open it.