# Link [tag:some_tag] to another Stack Exchange site

Tags: support, magic-links

In my profile I add

> [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) [Increase reputation required to add “k” in SE app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231060/increase-reputation-required-to-add-k-in-se-app)

and "Save And Copy To All Stack Exchange Accounts".

On Meta Stack Exchange `[tag:status-completed]` linked to [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), as it should.
But on other sites it is linked to status-completed tag posts on them - in my Stack Overflow profile it is linked to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-completed.

I tried to place it in hyperlink:

```
<a href = "https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed">
[tag:status-completed]
</a>
```

or

```
[ [tag:status-completed] ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed)
```

but it doesn't work.

Is it possible to link `[tag:some-tag]` to specific Stack Exchange site?

Comment: @animuson How to solve my problem? Why in question, which you marked my question as duplicate of, tag "css" links to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css, but not to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/css

Comment: Because the tag links weren't updated when the MSO/MSE split occurred. If you try editing the post, it will update to an MSE link.

Comment: @animuson May I make a feature request about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only possible `[tag` magic links are for tags on the current site and its meta site (if not already a meta site).

There is no support in magic tag links for tags on completely other Stack Exchange sites.

---

For tags on the current site, you use `[tag:<tag name>]`, for those on the meta site, you use `[meta-tag:<tag-name>]`.

Comment: I know about meta-tag. Maybe make `[mso-tag:<tag name>]`?

Comment: This should be revaluated. It's an obvious feature that should be there. [On a question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/186498/2639) on [dba.se] already answered, I wanted to comment `"If you need mere synonym's in the future check out [english.se]'s  [english.se:word-choice]" tag`