# The powerfullest ever mod, or: do we really need to display the gold badge icon after a user receives a diamond?

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-declined, dupehammer

[That's what happens](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/232161/link-tagsome-tag-to-another-stack-exchange-site) if a user who is gold-badge-holder dupehammers a question and then finds somewhere a spare diamond:

> [image]

Looks great, I must say. But what's the need?

I think that the badge icon should be removed then.

Comment: +1 but is this really a bug? Sounds more like a feature request to me... ;p

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ McBigBug.

Comment: @nicael I would say that this lies in between a bug and a [tag:feature-request]. It could get both tags IMHO.

Comment: @yo seems that you're right :)

Comment: Since [this is now official](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268288/show-the-gold-badge-in-addition-to-the-diamond-when-a-moderator-closes-as-a-dupl), this one here should be tagged [tag:status-declined].

Comment: @Sha I don't get the linked question, as the thing it was asking for was already the case....

Comment: So looks like they removed the gold icon at some point, forgot to mark this request as completed (or just missed it) and were convinced by the opposite request to put it back.

Comment: @nicael It will now always add the gold badge indicator whenever a moderator closes as a duplicate, even if they are currently a moderator.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The two icons serve different roles.

- The badge icon is an indication that the user applied a binding vote.
- The diamond is an indication that  the user *currently* has diamond privileges. It is **not** an indication of a binding vote being used. This symbol has no direct connection to the closure event, and therefore does not make the badge icon redundant.

Suppressing the badge icon would be misleading, because it'd suggest that animuson used diamond-mod power before he in fact had it.

Elsewhere, I proposed that [Binding closevotes should be recorded for moderators as they are for gold badge owners](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240169/); that is, the closure banner should have an indication of binding vote (of whatever kind) that is distinct from the current moderator status of the user.