# Show the gold badge in addition to the diamond when a moderator closes as a duplicate

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, moderators, dupehammer

**(tl;dr) When a moderator closes as a duplicate - if they have a gold badge in the tag(s) they're doing so -- display the gold badge in addition to the diamond**

I think it's fair to say that moderators are also active users on their respective site(s) and are most likely "domain knowledge experts" in one or more fields (ie tags) -- and sometimes, yes, when we're not doing our duties as a moderator, we may like to ask questions or answer questions.

"My" site is Stack Overflow - my main tag is "Python" - pretty much all of my "reputation" comes from that tag and I'm honoured that the community  has given me the privilege on that tag to "dupehammer" using my gold badge.

What I find a bit uncomfortable is (as a mod) it will put the diamond next to my name which makes it looks a moderator action rather than a "user" action.

I'm not qualified to close-as-a-dupe many things (and I don't unless the community can prove why and hasn't done so already (requires moderator intervention))

Comment: Why not just show both?

Comment: @Mat'sMug indeed why not... it doesn't disguise that a user is a mod (as per the concern in Patrick's answer), but at the same time keeps the same principle. "A user that gold that's a gold badge holder - they just happen to also be a mod"

Comment: Note: this FR is plagia-inspired by my comment [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268278/it-looks-like-the-duplicate-banner-changed-how-does-it-work-now#comment869583_268278) ;)

Comment: This was completed (as per Patrick's suggestion, we show both the gold badge and the moderator diamond).

Comment: That's nice. Thanks @ThomasOrozco. Any sample question we can see this on?

Comment: @PatrickHofman This will only happen for questions closed by moderators with a gold badge from here on out. Maybe Jon can post a link to the next Python question he closes as a duplicate on SO!

Comment: @PatrickHofman sample question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/268893/260841 :)

Answer (score 18):

If you want to show your gold tag badge, do it next to the diamond (as per [Mat's Mug's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/197901/mats-mug) suggestion), not instead of it, as in the initial request. That will actually add to the dialog that the user is an expert on the subject too, but won't hide his powers.

---

For completeness: I disagree with the initial request to hide the diamond. The diamond comes with extra responsibility. Showing the gold tag badge hides that a user is actually a moderator. We should make this as visible as possible to avoid confusion.

Closing as a duplicate is only a small task you do as a moderator. I expect a lot of confusion when you first are associated with the gold tag badge (since you are closing as a duplicate) and the second time with a diamond (since you are closing as off-topic). Only for this specific case you want to deviate from the standard, and that seems wrong to me.

Comment: I have no intention of "hiding powers" -- the main thing is differentiating between a mod decision and someone that happens to know a thing or two about the tag. I'd be perfectly happy if it displayed a gold badge closure with the diamond next to it -- that way it doesn't "disguise" anything but at the same time, makes it clear that I didn't dupe as a mod kind of thing

Comment: Agreed, I've edited the question. (You can basically think of the question as co-owned by us.)

Comment: So this is a joined request from the mods on SO? If so, it would be nice to find that back in the question @BoltClock'saUnicorn

Comment: @JonClements I swapped the answer to agree with your updated post, but left my initial concerns for completeness. Do you think it is okay like this?

Comment: Well not collectively, just the two of us. I don't know if the other mods are as interested as we are. I wasn't sure if it was worth spending my time writing up a FR, so I personally didn't do more than leave a comment on another question.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is a good idea, for two reasons:

1. Technically, moderator status "overrides" dupe hammer - when casting a close vote, the first check is "Is this a moderator?" and if so, the vote becomes binding. Only in case of a  "nope, not moderator" it continue to check "Does the user casting the vote have a gold tag badge in proper tag?" etc. So to be technically correct, only one symbol should show.
2. Noise. Is your gold badge really relevant? No, it's not. You closed the question by being a moderator, and that's what should show. Any extra information about you would be noise.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking. No need to show the gold tag badge if you are a moderator.

Comment: I suppose it does become redundant if I make sure I only ever dupehammer questions where I have a gold tag badge.

Comment: This behavior was surprising enough that I assumed it was either a bug or some sort of oversight.  I'm surprised it was done on purpose!

Comment: I find it really helpful that a gold badge is shown; users find it more acceptable if a question was closed as a dupe by an expert in the tag, rather than by a community moderator.