# Why do I have ten times less unicorn points?

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, android-app

Am I ten times less worthy? :-(

[image: screenshot]

I actually have 22k rep on SO, 18k on meta, and 15k on PPCG, but the app shows them divided by ten.

Comment: Yup me too in the Android app.

Comment: Tip: appending `l` to the end of the filename (as in `UwQq0SFl.png`) reduces it to the box of dimensions 640x640, which is still perfectly readable without being overly large.

Comment: small Android screen can handle only small numbers

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm apparently really bad at orders of magnitude. I broke this during my fix for [Increase reputation required to add “k” in SE app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231060/increase-reputation-required-to-add-k-in-se-app), I've gone ahead and just made this view not trim the reputation (exactly like how it's displayed when looking at a site's users), so as of version 1.0.39 it'll look like this:

[image]